# python / pandas: How to count each cluster of unevenly distributed distinct values in each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am transitioning from excel to python and finding the process a little daunting. I have a pandas dataframe and cannot find how to count the total of each cluster of '1's' per row and group by each ID (example data below).

```
    ID      20-21   19-20   18-19   17-18   16-17   15-16   14-15   13-14   12-13   11-12
0   335344      0       0       1       1       1       0       0       0       0       0
1   358213      1       1       0       1       1       1       1       0       1       0
2   358249      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3   365663      0       0       0       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
```

The result of the above in the format

```
ID
    LastColumn Heading a '1' occurs: count of '1's' in that cluster
```

would be:

```
335344
    16-17: 3

358213
    19-20: 2
    14-15: 4
    12-13: 1

365663
    13-14: 5
```

There are more than 11,000 rows of data I would like to output the result to a txt file. I have been unable to find any examples of how the same values are clustered by row, with a count for each cluster, but I am probably not using the correct python terminology. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape. Then create consecutive groups by compare for not equal [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to new column `g`. Then filter rows with only `1` and aggregate by named aggregation by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(name='value')

df['g'] = df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()

df1 = (df[df['value'].eq(1)].groupby(['ID', 'g'])
         .agg(a=('level_1','last'), b=('level_1','size'))
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
       ID      a  b
0  335344  16-17  3
1  358213  19-20  2
2  358213  14-15  4
3  358213  12-13  1
4  365663  13-14  5
```

Last for write to `txt` use [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df1.to_csv('file.txt', index=False)
```

If need your custom format in text file use:

```
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    for i, g in df1.groupby('ID'):
        f.write(f"{i}\n")
        for a, b in g[['a','b']].to_numpy():
            f.write(f"\t{a}: {b}\n")
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael.  All worked except the custom format that gave the error: "None of [Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]".

Comment: @Sara - Mea culpa, it is `df1.groupby('ID')`, not `df.groupby('ID')`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the sum method and then specify which axis you would like to sum on. To get the sum of each row, create a new series equal to the sum of the row.

```
# create new series equal to sum of values in the index row
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)    # specifies index (row) axis
```

The best method for getting the sum of each column is dependent on how you want to use that information but in general the core is just to use the sum method on the series and assign it to a variable.

```
# sum a column and assign result to variable
foo = df['20-21'].sum()    # default axis=0
bar = df['16-17'].sum()    # default axis=0
print(foo)    # returns 1
print(bar)    # returns 3
```

You can get the sum of each column using a for loop and add them to a dictionary. Here is a quick function I put together that should get the sum of each column and return a dictionary of the results so you know which total belongs to which column. The two inputs are 1) the dataframe 2) a list of any column names you would like to ignore

```
def get_df_col_sum(frame: pd.DataFrame, ignore: list) -> dict:
    """Get the sum of each column in a dataframe in a dictionary"""
    # get list of headers in dataframe
    dfcols = frame.columns.tolist()
    # create a blank dictionary to store results
    dfsums = {}
    # loop through each column and append sum to list
    for dfcol in dfcols:
        if dfcol not in ignore:
            dfsums.update({dfcol: frame[dfcol].sum()})
    return dfsums
```

I then ran the following code

```
# read excel to dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(test_file)
# ignore the ID column
ignore_list = ['ID']
# get sum for each column
res_dict = get_df_col_sum(df, ignore_list)
print(res_dict)
```

and got the following result.

> {'20-21': 1, '19-20': 1, '18-19': 1, '17-18': 3, '16-17': 3, '15-16':
> 2, '14-15': 2, '13-14': 1, '12-13': 1, '11-12': 0}

Sources: [Sum by row](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sum-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python), [Pandas Sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), [Add pairs to dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-a-keyvalue-pair-to-dictionary-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. I already have the sum's per year (column). I was specifically after the count of each cluster of '1's' for each ID, ie: by row.